# How to hydrate result of query in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following tables:
[Database Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMN30.png)

using this stored procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE test.sp_getEmployeeProfile(IN _empId BIGINT)
            BEGIN
                SELECT test.employees.id, 
                    test.employees.full_name, 
                    test.profiles.favorite_food, 
                    test.profiles.favorite_color,
                FROM test.employees 
                INNER JOIN test.profiles
                    ON test.employees.id = test.profiles.employee_id 
                WHERE test.employees.id = _empId;
            END
```

And the following models:

Employee Model

```php
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use App\Profile;
    use App\Friend;
    
    class Employee extends Model
    {
        public $timestamps = false;
    
        public function profile()
        {
            return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
        }
    }
```

Profile Model

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Employee;

class Profile extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function employee()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class);
    }
}
```

In the `show($id)` method of my controller:

```php
$employee = DB::select('call sp_getEmployeeFriends(?)',[$id]);
$employee = Employee::hydrate($employee);
```

The `hydrate()` method is not including the relationships. Is there a way to include the relationships?

[Before Hydrate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpqMT.png)

[After Hydrate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QA6Kw.png)

Comment: What does `dump($employee)` look like before and after the call to `Employee::hydrate()`?

Comment: Edited my question to show before and after `hydrate()`

Comment: Because you don't get the profile ID, it seems like it would be very difficult to work out a way to include this as a relationship. You're expecting to be able to do `$employee->profile->favorite_color`?

Comment: I think the concept of relationships in Laravel very much depends on direct access to the underlying records. Maybe you could create `favorite_food` and `favorite_color` properties on the model that would get populated by the hydration?

Comment: Thanks @miken32, you are right I want to be able to do `$employee->profile->favorite_color`. Are you suggesting that I create a new Model that includes `favorite_food` and `favorite_color` and disregard the existing models?

Comment: No just add `public $favorite_colour` to your existing model. I don't know if `hydrate()` will populate it or not, but worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

If using stored procedure is not a must you can get the same result with the following

```php
public function show($id)
{
    $employee = Employee::with('profile:id,employee_id,favorite_food,favorite_color')
        ->select('id', 'full_name')
        ->findOrFail($id);

    return view('employee.show', ['employee' => $employee]);
}
```

Comment: Sadly it is required... The DBAs are the ones providing us with ways to retrieve data.